# Find straight line distance from point to raster cells

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, distance

I have a single point as a shapefile and I have a raster layer that indicates wetlands.  Each cell is 5m x 5m and there are about 12 "island" wetlands.  I'd like to be able to find the straight line distance to each cell within each wetland - presumably it would be centroid of each raster cell.  The cells don't contain any specific attributes just a binary value of 1, but I would like to populate each cell with the distance to the point.

I've tried Euclidian distance, but that doesn't give me the result I want, as it goes around the wetlands as they are considered barriers.

Are they any tools in ArcGIS Pro that can do this - seems pretty simple, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I don't know about arcgis, but other programs call this grid distance with an ignore  (ignore = certaincellvalue) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I just converted the raster to a point feature class and ran the near function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).